# How to add new flex elements as columns instead of rows in this layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to build a layout that looks like the below:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background: floralwhite;
  margin: 0 5vw 10vh 5vw;
}

div:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Except, the problem is that additional `<div>` elements are added as new rows.

How can this layout be achieved with new `<div>` elements added as new columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was that you need to specify a height on `<section>` so new columns would appear on the right instead of below.

```css
section {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 40vh;
  background: floralwhite;
  margin: 0 5vw 10vh 5vw;
}

div:nth-of-type(2n + 1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your CSS:

```
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```